# Select all values in 1 view ( can't use procedure and temp tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a View with select in my database. It must be view can't use stored procedure so it needs to be created in just one query without temp tales.

I create a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporaryTable          -- Local temporary table - starts with single #
(
    id int,
    date_order date,
    order_status varchar(50)
);


insert into #TemporaryTable
VALUES
('1','2022-01-01','Completed'),
('2','2022-01-01','Cancelled'),
('3','2022-01-01','Completed'),
('4','2022-01-01','Completed'),
('5','2022-01-02','Cancelled'),
('6','2022-01-02','Cancelled'),
('7','2022-01-02','Completed'),
('8','2022-01-02','Completed'),
('9','2022-01-02','Completed'),
('10','2022-01-03','Cancelled'),
('11','2022-01-04','Completed')



select * from #TemporaryTable


SELECT COUNT(crm1.date_order) AS [count_all_orders], crm1.date_order AS [date_order],COUNT(crm2.date_order) AS [[count_cancelled_orders]
FROM            #TemporaryTable crm1 WITH (nolock)
left outer join #TemporaryTable crm2 WITH (nolock) on crm2.id = crm1.id and crm2.order_status ='Cancelled'
GROUP BY crm1.date_order,crm2.date_order
```

[SQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d0e0315e5b986223d7899331686421a)

The endpoint is to have 1 date and count all orders + count cancelled orders.

[image]

Now the date is doubled and giving bad values. Please check that in SQL fiddle and help me.
Thank you!

Comment: `NOLOCK` on a temporary table is a serious code smell. When if your temporary table, that is scoped ***only*** to you and the scope your using, *ever* going to be used by a different scope? (This is a trick question, the answer is **never**.) I would suggest you have *no idea* what `NOLOCK` does and thus should not be using it.

Comment: I just rebuild code for example... I have local tables temp is only here for example :) and forget to delete it from my select

Comment: I think that just cements that you have no idea what `NOLOCK` does then, considering you rebuilt your code to use `NOLOCK` on locally scoperd temporary tables...

Comment: I'm not asking about nolock it's not point here ehh.. but thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to join, you can simply use conditional aggregation:

> `COUNT(someNonNullValue)` and `COUNT(*)` are the same thing

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS count_all_orders,
  crm1.date_order,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN crm2.order_status = 'Cancelled' THEN 1 END) AS count_cancelled_orders
FROM #TemporaryTable crm
GROUP BY
  crm.date_order;
```

> `NOLOCK` is a very bad idea. Only use it in exceptional circumstances.

Comment: exacly , thank you!